# Definition: Prime splits/is inert in infinite extension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $M/F$ be an infinite algebraic extension where $F$ is a number field. What does it mean for a nonzero prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\subset\mathcal{O}_F$ to split completely in $M$? Is it just that $\mathfrak{p}$ splits completely in every intermediate number field $M/L/F$, or something different? Similarly if $\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_M$ is prime, is $\mathfrak{p}$ then inert in $M$?

Edit: Note $[M:F]=\infty$, so $M$ is not a number field.

Comment: you are asking if it is possible to construct a sequence of finite extension $L_{n+1}/L_n/F$ where one prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subset \mathcal{O}_F$ splits more and more ?

Comment: No. I am asking what it means for $\mathfrak p$ to be totally split or inert in $M$. I know what it means when $M$ is a number field, but I don't know what it means when $M$ is an algebraic extension of infinite degree.

Comment: Can you construct a sequence of extension where a prime splits more and more ?

Comment: Your definitions are both valid (although note that being inert in every finite subextension is not sufficient to be inert). However, when dealing with infinite extensions, it is easiest to work with Galois extensions, and define these properties via the decomposition and inertia groups.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Okay I think I've almost got it for Galois extensions. Unramified means trivial inertia group, totally split means trivial decomposition group, and I've read that that's equivalent to unramified with trivial Frobenius, and then inert should mean unramified and the decomposition group is the Galois group. Is that correct?

Comment: Sounds good to me

Comment: @Mathmo123 Okay, thank you!